# Calendar Column to Custom List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, calendar

I know there is a way, but not sure how to do it.  I want to pull a date column from a calendar list and have it appear in a custom list.  The purpose is to so when others enter a date into calendar and will automatically populate the custom list.

Can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to view your calendar events in a list style ?

Comment: Lookup your calendar column in your custom list

Comment: @JayHell yes, I would like to view them in a list style or a calendar view if possible

Comment: @AtishDipongkor Are you saying to choose lookup column and select the calendar with that particular column?  I have never created a lookup from a calendar list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on what your needs are. Reading your post "The purpose is to so when others enter a date into calendar and will automatically populate the custom list".

From what I can tell, you have a Calendar and when a date is entered, you want it to populate a custom list. Are you wanting it to populate an existing item in the custom list or a new list item being created with the date value?

You could create a simple workflow to run when an item is created on your calendar and wait for the date column to have a value. Once a value is detected, you could either create the list item or update a list item.

Comment: Thank you, Matt! Yes, I want it to update an existing item.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact requirements. But as @Matt stated, the workflow would do the trick.

From my point of view, I would simply use the "All Events" view to show you your calendar information in a list style. That way, you wouldn't have to care about synchronizing the data between the two lists. i.e. event deletion, event update. Those cases would have to be taken care with the workflow, thus copying more information to ensure unicity...

I'm not a big fan of data duplication, maybe you can bring the requirements of your second list directly into the calendar list.

Comment: Thank you, JayHell.  When you say "maybe you can bring the requirements of your second list directly into the calendar list", can you explain more?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by copying the date into the second list ?